# Complex : Framework 3.5 install but specific framework 3.5 code doesn't work

Tags: .net

I have a very strange problem.
On a Windows 2008 DataCenter R2 I have installed IIS and Framework 3.5 but when I run a code specific for DotNet 3.5 I have an issue.
The goal is to Read all users Session (http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/05/reading-all-users-session.aspx)

This is the code to understand the problem and maybe test it by yourself :

```
object obj = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("CacheInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null);

foreach (FieldInfo ofi in obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
Label1.Text += ofi.Name + "<br/>";
}
```

With framework 3.5 the return should be
- _disposed
- _caches
- _cacheIndexMask
- _cacheCommon

but on my server the result is 
_entries
_expires
_usage
_lock
_disposed
_totalCount
_publicCount
_maxCount
_maxCountOverload
_flushUndercount
_insertBlock
_useInsertBlock
_insertBlockCalls
_utcLastTrimCompleted
_iSubCache
_cacheMultiple
_cacheCommon

like with the Framework 2

I have 2 servers, one is ok with my code and System.Environment.Version is 2.0.50727.4927
on the other, with the problem, System.Environment.Versionis= 2.0.50727.5456

I have already try to uninstall/reinstall Framework 3.5

I hope someone can help me.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

A way...
By reintall from zero my Windows 2008 R2 DataCenter server, I have choose in "role / functionnalities" this specific order :

1 - I check FrameWork3.5
2 - the system ask to install IIS, I check the checkboxes

and not the reverse, ie start by checked IIS and after Framework 3.5

and now it's good, my code return what I want  :
_disposed
_caches
_cacheIndexMask
_cacheCommon

The problem is not solved, the first line of code
    object obj = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("CacheInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null);

return a CacheMultiple or CacheSingle object so their is consequence in the end of code

But why from the server one or the other object return is not the same?

Antoher important point , System.Environment.Version = 2.0.50727.4927 but before it was 2.0.50727.5456 
I don't know the difference between the 2but the problem doesn't come from thisbecause on my dev machine, I have 2.0.50727.5456 and the first code line return the good object : CacheMultiple